# bash script - cant create a directory?

Tags: linux, bash

i am trying to create a directory where i then later mount a hdd partition to it.

However, i keep gettin this error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/20220630232331’: Permission denied
```

Here the part it fails:

## Mount a ext4 drive

```
function mountExt4Drive {
    uuid=$1
    location="20220630232331"
    mkdir "/home/$location"
    echo "mounting ext4 hdd $uuid in $location"
    mount UUID=$uuid $location
}
```

I executed this command before runing the above bash script to make it executable via:

```
chmod +x auto_mount_hdd.sh
```

i tried even adding sudo on mkdir but that prompts me to type in my password which i dont wnat to, i want this to be a automative process.

Comment: Are you running this as root? You need to run it from a user that has write permission to `/home`

Comment: Are you trying to mount this in your home directory? You should use `"$HOME/$location"` for that.

Comment: But usually only root is allowed to mount filesystems.

Comment: hi, i am running this on a normal user just to test to see if the script all works. the plan is to automatically run the script as soon as my server boots up.

Is there a way to run this as root for testing purposes and is there also a way for this script to autmatically run by a root user after startup?

Comment: For testing, run the script as root with `sudo ./auto_mount_hdd.sh uuid`. You'll have to enter your password for this.

Comment: How you run a script automatically at startup depends on your distribution. If you need help figuring that out, the place to ask is [unix.se].

Comment: @Jono Your OS almost certainly has a way of auto-mounting such as /etc/fstab.

Comment: you can also explore [suid](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/suid-sgid-sticky-bit) option, if you want others who are non-root to execute this script. But make sure that the commands inside use the fully qualified path so that users may not override the commands with local copies which may do other things.